# Building a prediction model in R studio with keras

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a Prediction model through Keras tensor flow in R studio but I am getting an error as below. Pls does anyone have a clue? this is my first time using Keras or deep learning and R as well. Please help me out, and suggest the changes. Thanks, mate!

library(keras)

> train_data <-read.csv(file="trialtrainfinal.csv",head=FALSE)
>   test_data <-read.csv(file="trialtest.csv",head=FALSE)
>   train_targets <-read.csv(file="traintarget.csv",head=FALSE)
>
> mean <- apply(train_data, 2, mean)
>   std <- apply(train_data, 2, sd)
>   train_data <- scale(train_data, center = mean, scale = std)
>   test_data <- scale(test_data, center = mean, scale = std)
>
> build_model <- function() {
>   +   model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
>   +     layer_dense(units = 64, activation = "relu",
>   +                 input_shape = dim(train_data)[[2]]) %>%
>   +     layer_dense(units = 64, activation = "relu") %>%
>   +     layer_dense(units = 1)
>   +
>   +   model %>% compile(
>   +     optimizer = "rmsprop",
>   +     loss = "mse",
>   +     metrics = c("mae")
>   +   )
>   + }
>
> k <- 4
>   indices <- sample(1:nrow(train_data))
>   folds <- cut(1:length(indices), breaks = k, labels = FALSE)
>   num_epochs <- 100
>   all_scores <- c()
>   for (i in 1:k) {
>   +   cat("processing fold #", i, "\n")
>   + val_indices <- which(folds == i, arr.ind = TRUE)
>   +   val_data <- train_data[val_indices,]
>   +   val_targets <- train_targets[val_indices,]
>   +
>   +
>   +   partial_train_data <- train_data[-val_indices,]
>   +   partial_train_targets <- train_targets[-val_indices]
>   +
>   +
>   +   model <- build_model()
>   +
>   +
>   +   model %>% fit(partial_train_data, partial_train_targets,
>   +                 epochs = num_epochs, batch_size = 1, verbose = 0)
>   +
>   +
>   +   results <- model %>% evaluate(val_data, val_targets, verbose = 0)
>   +   all_scores <- c(all_scores, results$mean_absolute_error) 
>   + }
>   processing fold # 1
>   Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
>     ValueError: No data provided for "dense_5". Need data for each key in: ['dense_5']

Detailed traceback: 
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\r-reticulate\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 728, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\r-reticulate\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 224, in fit
    distribution_strategy=strategy)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\r-reticulate\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 547, in _process_training_inputs
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\r-reticulate\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 594, in _process_inputs
    steps=steps)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\r-reticulate\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 2519, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\r-reticul

When I use the command "summary(model)", I get the following results:  Model: "sequential"

---

## Layer (type)                                                                 Output Shape                                                          Param #

dense (Dense)                                                                (None, 64)                                                            896

---

dense_1 (Dense)                                                              (None, 64)                                                            4160

---

## dense_2 (Dense)                                                              (None, 1)                                                             65

Total params: 5,121
Trainable params: 5,121
Non-trainable params: 0

---

Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: No data provided for "dense_2". Need data for each key in: ['dense_2']

Answer (score 0):

Given the error message, it suggests that the data that is being fed into the model is not correctly populated.  You may want to confirm that the partial_train_data and partial_train_targets actually have values in them, and are consistent in terms of shape etc with each other and what the network is expecting based on the design.  There should be a command you can use like model.summary() right after the model build step which returns the network architecture in terms of data shapes/dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I just edited the question to display the results for summary(model), can u take a look at it....sorry for bugging you.

Comment: After trying to reproduce your issue, I discovered a typo which I believe is probably the main problem.  In the line:  "partial_train_targets <- train_targets[-val_indices]"  you are missing the comma after val_indices which is producing an empty input to the model.  The line above that "partial_train_data <- train_data[-val_indices,]" has it correct.  This might help get you further along.  I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was a syntax error at last... I got rid of the error, but now the "all_scores" returns "null" ... I guess I'll just have to get over the basics neatly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert train_data and test_data to a matrix. 
Use data.matrix or as.matrix